# QTP: Unique browser identificator not related to title?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

In my QTP keywrord driven automation, I would like to open browser and then automatically call all functions on that browser. I noticed it does work even when the browser title changes but I am not sure whether its coincidence or not.
I would need to open browser with e.g. ID and then simply call Browser("MyID"). functions. Is there any way or I can rely on QTP even when the browser changes its name?

Answer (score 1):

QTP doesn't use the title to identify the browser, the description usually is based on when the browser was created (see the *Creation Time* ordinal identifier). So if the state of your machine is the same (no other browsers were open before beginning to test) then the identification should be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

During your testing, if there's only one Browser window open all the time , then
Just adding a "Browser" object in your OR , without any identification property would work.

If there are multiple browsers open, then you might have to add one or more of 
Name
Title
Creation time.

Avoid using Creation time though.